# Let DIV break out of Bootstrap 4 container

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I'm using a container in Bootstra 4 to center the conent of my page in the middle of the browser. So far so normal.

But I need something more. The content inside the container should break out on the left side and should grow to the browser-window. But only on the left side.

Because I'm using the slick slider, I can't use `position:absolute` or something else on a single object in the container DIV. I need an whole DIV inside the container to grow to the left side. And I need the container to align it on the right side to the rest of the page.

Here is my actual code: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/erQJey

This is what I need. The image inside the slides should grow to the left.
The blue background is the browser window:

[image]

```
<div class="bg-dark">
    <div class="container bg-white">
        <div class="slider">
            <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2500x500" class="img-fluid"></div>
            <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2500x500" class="img-fluid"></div>
            <div><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/2500x500" class="img-fluid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        draggable: false,
        fade:true,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplaySpeed: 4000,
        speed:1200,
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can not do that in Bootstrap unless you use two containers or a fluid-container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ([codepen](https://codepen.io/DessaugesAntoine/pen/xjQebP))

HTML:

```
<div class="bg-dark">
    <div class="container bg-white">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
        Slider
    </div>
    <div class="container bg-white">
        Content2
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var width = $(window).width() - (($(window).width() - 
$('.container').outerWidth() ) / 2);
$('.slider').width(width+'px');

$( window ).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width() - (($(window).width() - $('.container').outerWidth() ) / 2);
    $('.slider').width(width+'px');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what I need. I want the slider inside the container and just let it outgrow it on one side. And it should stay in the container on the other side (middle of the page).

Comment: @Cray I can't visualize the result. If you have an example it will help

Comment: I added an image

Comment: Looking a [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/5ox31m2a/) of slick slider, it should be done by slick slider. @Cray

Comment: I don't see how that could help, sorry.

Comment: ah ok, no problem :-)

Comment: I don't really know how to do it, but maybe you could put your all slider in a div, put this div in position absolute and left 0. And with some js you change the width of this new div to : container.width + ((page.width - container.width) / 2).
Maybe tricky but I try :P

Comment: @Cray I edited my answer with how you can possibly do it

Comment: Thanks! It works but it doesn't resize the container in smaller screens. Do I miss something?

Comment: Humm, Maybe you can use the bootsrap class `container-fluid` instead of `container` just for the slider ? And add a padding-right ?
I think you should just not use bootstrap for this part. Or use it with the column. Like give `col-md-1` for left and right part and `col-md-10` for the content and when you have your slider you put in a `col-col-md-11` with an empty `col-md-1`. Still tricky :/

Comment: I will try that but I think it wouldn't be accurate in the middle. What if I don't use bootstrap?

Comment: You're welcome ! Happy to find a solution and was an interesting problem.

Comment: one last question: is there a way to limit the JS code to the deskop view

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162353/execute-jquery-only-on-desktop-site-dont-execute-jquery-on-mobile) or just add an if when `$(window).width()` is bigger than the size you want.

Answer (score 5):

An answer for future readers seeking a CSS only solution. You can calculate the margin right based on the 1/2 the width of the Bootstrap `container`.

Left-align Bootstrap container: https://www.codeply.com/go/tnjA5Hn8Zs

```
.container-left {
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right: 15px;
}

@media (min-width:576px){
  .container-left {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: calc(50vw - 270px);
  }
}

@media (min-width:768px){
  .container-left {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: calc(50vw - 360px);
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px){
  .container-left {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: calc(50vw - 480px);
  }
}

@media (min-width:1200px){
  .container-left {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: calc(50vw - 570px);
  }
}
```