# Boostrap : background image in a .container at the very left of the screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

So I'm using bootstrap 4, and have layout which has a `container` class:

```
body
  #content.container
    .row
      .col-6
        | Awesome content
      .col-6
        | I like that
    .row
       .col-12 And so on
    .row
       .col-3.here Content with an image
    .row
      .col-12 And so on
```

Works really well.

But sometimes, my very-competent-but-not-aware-of-technical-contraints designer adds an image at the level of the `.here` class, but positioned on the left of the screen, which means **outside** the `.container`.

The only solution I know for now is to move the `.container` outside the layout and to repeat it, like so:

```
body
  #content
    .container
      .row
        .col-6
          | Awesome content
        .col-6
          | I like that
      .row
         .col-12 And so on
    div style="background-image: url(/images/example.jpg);"
      .container
        .row
         .col-3.here Content with an image
    .container
      .row
        .col-12 And so on
```

This is a pain because it completely breaks factoring, becomes neither DRY, nor responsive.

But do I have a choice?

Of course setting the image position in JS is even uglier. Or setting fixed position of the image isn't a solution either.

But I thought maybe, thanks to flexboxes, it is possible to write something like `div.uncontainer style="background-image: url('/images/example')"` that would make the div full width, ignoring the `.container` constraint.

Has anyone the same issue?
Is there a clean solution?

Thanks

Comment: You mean like this  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564131/bootstrap-full-width-with-2-different-backgrounds-and-2-columns

Comment: Interesting, and close to what I am asking, but in their solution, the `.container` class needs to be repeated, so it is close to the solution I have, which is not satisfying enough for me here.

Comment: Or this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565976/css-how-to-overflow-from-div-to-full-width-of-screen?lq=1

Comment: This is it! But in that case it works because container is a `%` of screen width, so `translateX` can be calculated. But in bootstrap case, it is fixed in px, so it is not possible.

Comment: Sure it can...but we'd need a demo to advise further.

Comment: Or you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392425/let-div-break-out-of-bootstrap-4-container/56778986#56778986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comments, especially @zim which is pretty much what I ended up doing.

I wrote a utility function to create the `.uncontainer` class, which builds a full width `div`, despite being contained within a `.container`.

Here it goes:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions', '~bootstrap/scss/variables';

@mixin make-uncontainer-responsive($max-widths: $container-max-widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
      // Still hesitating with two other attribute : margin-left and translateX;
      // Anyone has an opinion on this?
      left: calc((#{$container-max-width} - 100vw)/2);
    }
  }
}

.container {
  position: relative; // Hopefully this doesn't break anything for you
  .uncontainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    @include make-uncontainer-responsive();
  }
}
```

Apparently `100vw` is only IE9+ so I guess this is the best compatibility we can achieve. Bootstrap 4 is IE10+ so all is fine. :)

Hope this can help, I'm considering suggesting to make it default to bootstrap.